# How do I skip error causing executions in rust?

Tags: file, rust, directory

To learn rust I am coding a recursive directory traversal program from scratch.

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let paths = fs::read_dir("/").unwrap();
    for path in paths {
        println!("First: {:?}", path);
        let sub_paths = fs::read_dir(path.unwrap().path());
        for sub_path in sub_paths.unwrap() {
            println!("  Second: {:?}", sub_path);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is, it exists the execution if a folder doesn't have right access or if its a file. How do I skip error causing folders or files similar to `try...except`.

Comment: `unwrap` panics on error.  Just don't use it.

Comment: those `.unwrap()` calls are points where you are saying *"assume this result was successful"*, there are many ways to handle them besides "unwrapping" them. see [Recoverable Errors with Result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) from the Rust Book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

The one possible solution is to use `match`ing. Then `Ok(v)` branch will be kind of similar to `try` block and the `Err(e)` branch will be kind of similar to `catch` block. Finally it may looks like ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5dfb02ba293f0f0ca93c4a0f4312d813)):

```rust
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    match fs::read_dir("/") {
        Ok(may_be_entries_vec) => {
            for may_be_entry in may_be_entries_vec {
                println!("First: {:?}", may_be_entry);
                
                match may_be_entry {
                    Ok(entry) => {
                        let path = entry.path();
                        match fs::read_dir(&path) {
                            Ok(may_be_sub_entry_vec) => {
                                for may_be_sub_entry in may_be_sub_entry_vec {
                                    println!("  Second: {:?}", may_be_sub_entry);
                                }
                            },
                            Err(e) => {
                                eprintln!(
                                    "Couldn't obtain {:?} content. The error is {:?}",
                                    path,
                                    e
                                )
                            },
                        }
                    },
                    Err(_e) => {
                        // Ex: eprintln!("Entry is an error:{:?}", _e);
                    },
                }
            }
        },
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Couldn't obtain \"/\" content. The error is {:?}.", e);
        },
    }
}
```

## Option 2

Or you may would like to skip all the errors (which is not a good option but still an option) ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8992482cda31eb5bc8b3cb69571990ac)):

```rust
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    if let Ok(entries_vec) = fs::read_dir("/") {
        for may_be_entry in entries_vec {
            println!("First: {:?}", may_be_entry);
            
            if let Ok(entry) = may_be_entry {
                if let Ok(sub_entry_vec) = fs::read_dir(entry.path()) {
                    for may_be_sub_entry in sub_entry_vec {
                        println!("  Second: {:?}", may_be_sub_entry);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Option 3

Or you may prefer more functional-like style. Remember, that kind of use for `or_else` may be questionable. You can remove all `or_else` calls if you would like to skip all the errors.  ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d8b75fb811a80aaa06e2c0f1d322465d)):

```rust
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    fs::read_dir("/")
        .or_else(|e| {
            eprintln!("Couldn't obtain '/' content. The error is {:?}.", e); 
            Err(e)
        })
        .iter_mut()
        .flat_map(|i| i)
        .for_each(|may_be_entry|{
            println!("First: {:?}", may_be_entry);
            
            may_be_entry
            .or_else(|e| {
                // Ex: eprintln!("Entry is an error:{:?}", e);
                Err(e)
            })
            .iter()
            .map(|e| e.path())
            .map(|path| (fs::read_dir(&path), path))
            .for_each(|(read_dir_result, path)|{
                read_dir_result
                    .or_else(|e| {
                        eprintln!(
                            "Couldn't obtain '{:?}' content. The error is {:?}.",
                            path,
                            e
                        ); 
                        Err(e)
                    })
                    .iter_mut()
                    .flat_map(|i| i)
                    .for_each(|may_be_subentry|{
                        println!("   Second: {:?}", may_be_subentry);
                    });
            });
        });
}
```

P.S. The other possible approach is to use [`?` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/the-question-mark-operator-for-easier-error-handling.html) and have some tricky convesions from one kind of error to another. But I feel like it'll be too much.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `unwrap` except maybe when you're really sure the value is there. Instead, `match` an `Option` result against its two possibilities: `Some(value)` or `None`.

Match a `Result` against its two possibilities: `Ok(T)` or `Err(E)`.

See [an introduction to matching `Option` variants](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/error/option_unwrap.html) and [an intro to `Result` enums](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html).